# Could not find implementations for the following rules specified in the configuration

Tags: javascript, eslint, tslint, eslintrc, eslint-plugin-vue

I am converting my tslint to eslint using below

Reference : https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/tree/master/packages/eslint-plugin-tslint#usage

This is my `tslint.json` file:

https://github.com/kumaresan-subramani/ESlint-tester/blob/main/tslint.json

### my eslint.json file

```js
{
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es2021": true
    },
    "extends": [
        "eslint:recommended",
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"
    ],
    "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    "plugins": [
        "@typescript-eslint",
        "@typescript-eslint/tslint"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
        "project": "tsconfig.json"
    },
    "rules": {
        "@typescript-eslint/tslint/config": ["warn", {
          "lintFile": "./tslint.json", // path to tslint.json of your project
          "rules": {},
          "rulesDirectory": [
            "node_modules/tslint-eslint-rules/dist/rules"
          ]
        }]
      },
    "reportUnusedDisableDirectives": true

}
```

While giving below command i a facing an error

> yarn run eslint src

### Error

```js
D:\today\ESlint-tester>yarn run eslint src
yarn run v1.21.1
$ D:\today\ESlint-tester\node_modules\.bin\eslint src

Could not find implementations for the following rules specified in the configuration:
    chai-vague-errors
    no-redundant-jsdoc
    missing-optional-annotation
    no-backbone-get-set-outside-model
    no-banned-terms
    no-cookies
    no-delete-expression
    no-document-write
    no-document-domain
    no-disable-auto-sanitization
    no-duplicate-parameter-names
    no-empty-interfaces
    no-exec-script
    no-function-constructor-with-string-args
    no-function-expression
    no-for-in
    no-multiline-string
    no-multiple-var-decl
    no-unnecessary-bind
    no-unnecessary-semicolons
    no-octal-literal
    no-sparse-arrays
    no-string-based-set-immediate
    no-string-based-set-interval
    no-unused-imports
    no-with-statement
    prefer-array-literal
    promise-must-complete
    react-no-dangerous-html
    use-named-parameter
    max-func-body-length
    no-empty-line-after-opening-brace
Try upgrading TSLint and/or ensuring that you have all necessary custom rules installed.
If TSLint was recently upgraded, you may have old rules configured which need to be cleaned up.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using [typescript-eslint](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/tree/master/packages/eslint-plugin-tslint) which is a :

> ESLint plugin [that] wraps a TSLint configuration and lints the whole source using TSLint.

But the error message:

```
Could not find implementations for the following rules specified in the configuration:
```

comes from TSLint itself. The reason is that the rules in your `tslint.json` are not compatible with your TSLint version.

You have to either change the TSLint version or adapt the rules by reviewing the [TSLint ChangeLog](https://github.com/palantir/tslint/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md). Note that typescript-eslint need a 5.x or 6.x TSLint version (See its [package.json](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin-tslint/package.json)).

You can also check this SO question: [Update TSLint Errors : Could not find implementations for the following rules specified in the configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40924640/update-tslint-errors-could-not-find-implementations-for-the-following-rules-sp)